MAUI movable, non-modal, not resizable popup window
In my application I need a

non-modal,
not resizable,
not maximizable, not minimizeable

popup window that

always stays on top of the main application window
the user can move around on the screen
moves with the main application window if this is moves around

So far I have been experimenting with

CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.PopUp, but found no way to make it non-modal and movable by the user.
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window, but found no way to make it not resizeable, not maximizable, not minimizeable, always staying on top of the main application window

Update
Using the hints given in the comments the following works fine on Windows, but not on Android (Emulator). On Android the popup can only be panned left and right, but not up and down.
I do not use XAML in the app, but only code behind. Here are the relevant code snippets:
The main ContentPage:
public partial class MyApp : ContentPage
{
    // ...
    private static PanContainer panContainer = null;
    private static MyMovablePopUp popUp = null;
    // ...

    public MyApp() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView();
        this.Content = sv;
        sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Default;
        sv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Default;

        Grid baseZStack = new Grid(); // The base stack for the overlay (ZIndex) of the PopUp (+ PanContainer) over the main content page
        sv.Content = baseZStack;

        // the control that contains all elements of the main content page
        VerticalStackLayout vsl = new VerticalStackLayout();
        baseZStack.Children.Add(vsl);
        vsl.ZIndex = 1;
        vsl.Padding = new Thickness(LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN, 0, LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN, LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN);
        vsl.Spacing = 5;
        vsl.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        vsl.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

        // the control that contains the MyMovablePopUp
        panContainer = new PanContainer();
        baseZStack.Children.Add(panContainer);
        panContainer.ZIndex = 2;
        popUp = new MyMovablePopUp(this);
        panContainer.IsVisible = false;
        panContainer.Content = popUp;

        // ...  
    }
}

The definition of the "popup":
internal class MyMovablePopUp : Border
{
    private readonly MyApp app;
    // ...
    internal MyMovablePopUp(MyApp app) : base()
    {
        this.app = app;
        this.MinimumWidthRequest = 140;
        this.MaximumWidthRequest = this.MinimumWidthRequest;
        this.MinimumHeightRequest = 290;
        this.MaximumHeightRequest = this.MinimumHeightRequest;
        
        // ... add content
    }
}

The PanContainer based on the class given here
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
    double panX, panY;

    public PanContainer()
    {
        PanGestureRecognizer panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
    }

    void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                Content.TranslationX = panX + e.TotalX; 
                Content.TranslationY = panY + e.TotalY;
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                panX = Content.TranslationX;
                panY = Content.TranslationY;
                break;
        }
    }
}


What platform are you targeting on? Do you mean this GitHub issue?

It doesn't have to be a window. Any control with implemented draggable will do.

@Liqun Shen-MSFT: I target Windows and Android (+ IOS nice to have). The "DismissibleBorder" example shown in the GitHub issue is not exactly the use case, but may be I can start with it. I assume I have to use ZIndex for the popup control ? The application already uses ZIndex for a canvas over a different control in the app. Would that interfere with the popup control ?

That means you have to create your own custom control like H.A.H said, set the higher ZIndex, and add the PanGestureRecognizer for it,

Yes it works, thank you @Liqun Shen-MSFT and @H.A.H.! I used (and modified a bit) the PanContainer class shown here and put my "popup" inside it.

Well, it works on Windows but not on Android (Emulator). I will update my question with the respective code snippets.

@Liqun Shen-MSFT : Can you help with the Android (Emulator) problem ?

I can reproduce the question in Android. It relates to a known issue on GitHub, Pan not detected vertically when the recognizer is inside of a scrollview. So, you may follow up this issue.
The workaround is that using other layout instead of the ScrollView, e.g. set the Content of the ContentPage to Grid or ```StackLayout,
this.Content = baseZStack;

And it should work.

The workaround works, thank you again! I have put an #if ANDROID ... #else around it. And the panning is also no longer laggy on Android.
